A strange equality of distribution in Stochastic Processes
Αt Brzezniak, Zastawniak, Basic Stochastic Processes in Solution 6.7 we find the equality:
$P (η_1\leq s<η_1+η_2\leq t<η_1+η_2+η_3)=\int_{0}^{s}P(s<u+η_2\leq t<u+η_2+η_3)λe^{-λu}du$, where $η_i$ are independent and exponentially distributed random variables and $0\leq s<t$.
Of course $λe^{-λu}$ is the density of $η_1$ and we have somehow used the formula $P(η_1\leq s)=\int_{0}^{s}f_{η_1}du$, but I cannot understand the presence of "the rest" $P$ inside the integral.
So, could someone explain precisely this equality? Further is it possible to generalize this result? (e.g. to write something like $P(X\leq s<h(X,Y))=\int_{-\infty}^s P(s<h(u,Y))f_X(u)du$, where $X,Y$ independent and $h:\Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R$.)
Thanks a lot.

This is a consequence of a result in conditional expectation, see e.g Conditional expectation of Borel function of two independent variables for the proof: Given $X, Y$ are two independent random variables, $f$ be a Borel function, then:
$$
    \mathbb{E}[f(X, Y) \vert Y] = g(Y)
$$
where $g(y) = \mathbb{E}[f(X, y)]$.
Now, back to your post. Let
$$
   f(x, y, z) = 1\{x \le s < x + y \le t < x + y + z\}
$$
Then,
$$
   \mathbb{P}(\eta_1 \le s < \eta_1 + \eta_2 \le t < \eta_1 + \eta_2 + \eta_3) = \mathbb{E}[f(\eta_1, \eta_2, \eta_3)]
$$
By the property of conditional expectation,
$$
   \mathbb{E}[f(\eta_1, \eta_2, \eta_3)] = \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}(f(\eta_1, \eta_2, \eta_3) \vert \eta_1)]
$$
But, as $\eta_1$ and $(\eta_2, \eta_3)$ are independent, we have
$$
   \mathbb{E}[f(\eta_1, \eta_2, \eta_3) \vert \eta_1] = g(\eta_1)
$$
where
$$
   g(u) = \mathbb{E}[f(u, \eta_2, \eta_3)] = \mathbb{P}(u \le s < u + \eta_2 \le t < u + \eta_2 + \eta_3)
$$
Thus,
$$
     \mathbb{P}(\eta_1 \le s < \eta_1 + \eta_2 \le t < \eta_1 + \eta_2 + \eta_3) = \mathbb{E}(g(\eta_1)) = \int_0^\infty g(u)\lambda \exp(-\lambda u)du
$$
Notice that,
$$
   \begin{align*}
        &\ \int_0^\infty \mathbb{P}(u \le s < u + \eta_2 \le t < u + \eta_2 + \eta_3)\lambda \exp(-\lambda u)du \\
        &= \int_0^\infty 1\{u \le s\} \cdot \mathbb{P}(s < u + \eta_2 \le t < u + \eta_2 + \eta_3)\lambda \exp(-\lambda u)du \\
        &= \int_0^s \mathbb{P}(s < u + \eta_2 \le t < u + \eta_2 + \eta_3)\lambda \exp(-\lambda u)du
   \end{align*} 
$$

Two questions: a. What is $1{x\leq s ...}$? b. Right above why $P(η_1\leq s <...)=E(f(η_1,η_2,η_3))$?

@SK_ The notation $1{A}$ is the indicator function for event $A$. To put it simply, you can view $1{A}$ as a Bernoulli random variable with the probability of success is $\mathbb{P}(A)$. Thus, $$ \mathbb{E}[1{A}] = \mathbb{P}(A) $$

Ok. The symbol confused me. I am used to see the event as an index of the indicator function: $E( 1 _A)=P(A), A\in\mathcal F$.

Also, could we proceed by considering the probability as an intersection of events? I mean $P(η_1\leq s<η_1+η_2\leq t<η_1+η_2+η_3)=P({η_1\leq s})\cap {s<η_1+η_2\leq t<η_1+η_2+η_3}$.

@SK_ What you write down is correct, but I don't think it will help. What do you do after this step ? The events ${\eta_1 \le s}$ and ${s < \eta_1 + \eta_2 \le t < \eta_1 + \eta_2 + \eta_3}$ are not independent.

Something like that (I am writing unsuccessfully  $A,B$ for brevity): $P(A\cap B)=E(1_{A\cap B})=E(1_A1_B)=E(E(1_A1_B|η_1))=E(1_AE(1_B|η_1))=E(1_AE(1_B|η_1))$. I cannot manage after that.

@SK_ Ok, I get it. You do the same as my answer, see that $E(1_B \vert \eta_1) = h(\eta_1)$ where $h(x) = P(s < x + \eta_2 < t < x + \eta_2 + \eta_3)$, so essentially you go back to the original way to solve this.

That 's ok. Could you finally explain precisely the final integral equality in your main answer?  ("Notice that etc.")

@SK_ I just update my answer. Essentially, the inner probability in the integral will be $0$ if $u > s$

Intuitively it is comprehensible. However is it in fact some identity like $P(A\cap B)=1_AP(B)$?!
